# URI is not hierarchical (JAVA)

Tags: java, imagen, jar

Estoy teniendo un problema bastante incomodo. Genere un archivo ejecutable JAR de prueba, y me esta generando el siguiente error:

```
Exception en thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Trivia.Interfaz.<init>(Interfaz.java:74)  <= mi codigo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Empezando con el esquema interno de mi proyecto. Las imagenes del programa las tengo guardadas como paquetes aparte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se llama "assets" el paquete donde tengo las imagenes.

Pues bien, en el codigo cuando cargo las imagenes lo tengo escrito de la siguiente manera:

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("/assets/panama-16.png").toURI()));
```

Haciendolo de esta manera, no da ningun tipo de error y el programa corre normalmente en el IDE de netbeans, pero el problema empieza cuando genero el ejecutable JAR. Y lei por ahi que esto es causado por la razon de que al momento de generar el ejecutable, Netbeans lo que hace es comprimir todos esos archivos (ZIP), y por supuesto, ya con eso las cosas cambian drasticamente en cuanto al uso del URL.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo hacer que desde el archivo JAR corra normalmente todas esas imagenes dentro de algun paquete del projecto sin ningun problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que `getResource` the devuelve una URL. Cuando la URL apunta a un fichero del sistema de ficheros, no hay problema en crear un `File` con ellas, pero si es un recurso dentro de un jar entonces no corresponde abrirlo como `File`.

Mi favorito es usar siempre [`Class.getResourceAsStream(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)), que te devuelve un `InputStream` de donde puedes obtener el recurso.

Como `ImageIO.read` tiene una sobrecarga que acepta un `InputStream`, haz:

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/panama-16.png"));
```

Comment: Si corriges el error en tu código te ganas mi voto ;)

Answer (score 2):

Dentro del *.jar* no puedes usar `File`. Usa ImageIO.read(InputStream io) en vez.

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/assets/panama-16.png" ));
```

La razón porque no se puede usar un descriptor de archivos es que los datos dentro un *.jar* de hecho no son archivos. 
Ojo, la ruta dentro del *.jar* tiene que ser desde la raíz del jar, así empezar con `/`.

Answer (score 2):

Yo uso estos dos para imágenes que están en el jar:

```
Image imga = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/img/imagen.jpg")).getImage();

ImageIcon img=new ImageIcon(NombreClase.class.getResource("/res/img/imagen.jpg"));
```