# Reproducir una Imagen GIF en un JPanel sin usar URL (JAVA)

Tags: java, gif

Buenas!

Miren, tengo una clase llamada GIFPanel que hereda de la clase JPanel

```
package Trivia;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GIFPanel extends JPanel{
      private Image imagen;
      public GIFPanel(Image imagen){
          this.imagen = imagen;
      }

      @Override
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
          super.paintComponent(g);
          g.drawImage(imagen,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this);
      }     
}
```

En mi otra clase lo creo y le inserto una imagen cuya fuente fue desde una direccion web

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(new URL("https://media.giphy.com/media/l3q2XKiWAOl0qa1Tq/source.gif"));
menu = new GIFPanel(img);
```

Ok, funciona correctamente, el gif se reproduce hasta con el JAR generado.... pero... en realidad no es lo que busco. ¿Como asi?, hace unos dias atras pregunte sobre como cargar imagenes contenidas dentro de paquetes del mismo proyecto en JAVA que no fuesen a traves de URLs, ya que al momento de generar el archivo jar, el programa responde con errores.

Intente hacer lo mismo con el archivo GIF, pero ni siquiera el netbeans lo reconoce. . .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Ya el paquete assets contiene el GIF.*

Quiero evitar usar links de la web ya que al momento que exista una falla de conexion donde vaya a usarse, el programa se crasheara (se cierra).

Como le hago para que pueda reproducir el gif usando el archivo contenido en el paquete de mi proyecto?

Comment: publica el arbol  completo de tu proyecto porfavor

Comment: Listo @x-rw, ya esta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que te debería funcionar es cargar el archivo en un `byte[]` y luego construir el imagen usando `createImage(byte[] ba)`:

```
// puedes usar org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils para obtener el Inputstream como byte[]
byte[] ba = IOUtils.toByteArray(getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/assets/source.gif" ));
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(ba);
```

Como ves, cargas el contenido del recurso de tu *.jar* en la misma forma que en [tu otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46422/uri-is-not-hierarchical-java/46425#46425). Solamente esta vez lo cargas en un arreglo de bytes que usas para construir tu imagen del arreglo usando el `Toolkit` de awt.

Comment: Gracias! voy a empezar a incluir esa libreria nueva a menudo

Comment: apache commons es muy útil (no se llama commons por nada) sin embargo no es mandatorio, si quieres limitarte a la biblioteca de sistema podrías tambien leer el `byte[]` con un `ByteArrayInputStream`. Si quieres, te agrego a la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Yo uso este en un JLabel y después monto en un JPanel.

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/drawable/loading.gif")));
```